# How would a share the state of the same React component across multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have a React Component with a toggle on it (on or off). The on / off state is handled by the components own state (this.state).

But I want that state to remain when the user goes from one page to the next. For instance they are on home.html and then when user clicks to another page like about.html.

Also this is not a single page app. Do I want Redux or Mobox or some other state management tool? Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Retaining JavaScript state across multiple pages can be done using localStorage or cookies, or even url parameters. Asked and answered lots of times. Whether you should abuse React for a multi-page app is a different question (my answer would be a resounding "no")

Comment: Dang, if moving from one page to another involves full page refresh, you're either going to have to store state information in local storage (probably easier) or somehow communicate the state information back to server

Comment: So the answer is it can't be done in a local react component  without passing it along outside of it then?

Comment: A ReactComponent can easily initialize its state based on `localStorage`.

Comment: So localStorage is the best solution for this? If so that's cool. Just wanted to get feedback.

Answer (score 5):

> But I want that state to remain when the user goes from one page to the next.

As has been said in comments probably the most straight-forward way is to just store the state to localstorage and retrieve it when the component mounts.

```
class Toggle extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem("my_value");
    if (storedValue) {
      this.setState({ value: storedValue });
    }
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ value });
    localStorage.setItem("my_value", value);
  }
  render() {
    return ...
  }
}
```

> Also this is not a single page app. Do I want Redux or Mobox or some other state management tool? Suggestions are welcomed.

No, Redux and Mobx aren't necessary, they are state containers that have ways to persist to localstorage (for example [redux-localstorage](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage) and [mobx-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx-localstorage)), but the key is just persisting to localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not moving pages (whole page refresh) and only using different components then you can simply define a state in parent component and pass it in the child components along with a function that would toggle the state.

Function would look like this:

ToggleState = newState => this.setState({ myState : newState });

Pass this function as prop to child component.

Use it in child component as

This.props.toggle(newState);

**but if it is across multiple pages the  you can go for localstorage **

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: OP: "Also this is not a single page app. "  :)

Comment: @Aaron : My bad, redux / mobx should be a solution then.

Comment: So the comments above recommended localStorage? Mobx would be able to handle the page refresh?

Comment: Redux or Mobx doesn't solve this. Localstorage does. Redux and Mobx might make using localstorage easier, such as with redux-localstorage and mobx-localstorage libraries, but they aren't necessary.

Comment: Yes correct, the state tree would reload on page refresh. +1 for Localstorage.

Comment: Okay, I'm a little confused now.  Mobx wouldn't be able to handle the state across multiple pages, okay.

Comment: No, the state will not reload on page refresh. :) At least not out of the box. There are plugins to sync your state to localstorage but that's an addon. I'll post an answer...

Comment: But again that's not pure redux, we are using localstorage there too, right? Without any addons the state tree would reload.

Comment: Without addons the state tree is only in memory, so a page refresh would reset the state. If its a single-page route refresh the state tree would be preserved out of the box.

Comment: I believe it totally depends on the usecase whether you only want to use the local storage or want to sync redux with local storage. But in any way, local storage will have to be used to handle data on page refresh. Correct me if I am wrong @Aaron.